# Why is there white gap between header and box it is in?

Tags: css, sass, froala

Why is my Frola box and toolbar not working properly? There is a white gap as shown:

[This is what my box looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gubU.png)

This is what I have written and it still does not work

```
.fr-box {
  border-radius: $border-radius !important;
  border: thin solid $dark !important;
margin:0px !important;
padding:0 !important;

  .fr-counter {
    border-bottom-right-radius: $border-radius !important;
  }
}

.fr-toolbar {
  border-top: 0 !important;
  border-top-left-radius: $border-radius !important;
  border-top-right-radius: $border-radius !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  background: $dark !important;
  margin:0 !important;
padding:0 !important;
```

Comment: Can you please attach a sandbox/similar link to run your code? Also, don't use `!important;` everywhere! Try to avoid using `!important;` keyword.

Comment: What site can I use to make a sandbox? Thanks

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/